# Simple form label class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I want to use `simple-form` and `bootstrap` to generate a horizontal form with 2 rows. The first row should have two inputs side by side - one for first name with one label and the second row should have an input for email. My problem is that that label for the first row is not getting the `control-label` class that is required for the horizontal form to render correctly. However, all the proper classes are being applied to the `email` field.

Below is my code:

```
= simple_form_for @order, :url => '/product/process_order', :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f|
  .form-inputs
    .control-group
      = f.label :first, "Full and last name"
      .controls
        = f.input_field :first, :class => "span2", :placeholder => 'First'
        = f.input_field :last,  :class => "span3" , :placeholder => 'Last'

    = f.input :email, :placeholder => 'you@example.com'
```

Which generates:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/product/process_order" class="simple_form form-horizontal" id="new_order" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <div class="control-group">
       <label for="order_first">Full and last name</label>
         <div class="controls">
           <input class="string required span2" id="order_first" name="order[first]" placeholder="First" size="50" type="text">
           <input class="string required span3" id="order_last" name="order[last]" placeholder="Last" size="50" type="text">
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="control-group email required">
       <label class="email required control-label" for="order_email">
         <abbr title="required">*</abbr> Email
       </label>
       <div class="controls"><input class="string email required" id="order_email" name="order[email]" placeholder="you@example.com" size="50" type="email"></div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: what stopping u to define a class for your label anyway

Comment: I'm having the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

In your `config/initializers/simple_form.rb` file, find the label class line and set it to:

```
config.label_class = 'control-label'
```

---

Also, if you are using bootstrap, you can do a few other things in this file. This might also help you:

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.wrappers :my_wrapper, :class => 'control-group',
    :hint_class => :field_with_hint, :error_class => :field_with_errors do |b|

    b.use :html5

    b.use :placeholder

    b.optional :maxlength

    b.optional :pattern

    b.optional :min_max

    b.optional :readonly

    ## Inputs
    b.use :label
    b.wrapper :my_wrapper, :tag => 'div', :class => 'controls' do |ba|
      ba.use :input
      ba.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => 'span', :class => 'label label-important' }
      ba.use :hint,  :wrap_with => { :tag => 'p', :class => 'help-block' }
    end
  end

  config.default_wrapper = :my_wrapper

  config.boolean_style = :nested

  config.button_class = 'btn'

  config.error_notification_tag = :div

  config.error_notification_class = 'alert alert-error'

  config.label_class = 'control-label'

  config.form_class = 'form-horizontal'

  config.generate_additional_classes_for = [:wrapper, :label, :input]
  config.browser_validations = true
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I already have `label_class` set to `'control-label'` and it seems to be working appropriately for the `email` field. I'm not sure why it doesn't work for the label where I specify the label text.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/SimpleForm/FormBuilder%3alabel) you have to do something along the lines of this:

`f.label :first, label: 'Full and last name'`